# DataGrid Filter Method Very Slow

Tags: c#, beginner, database, wpf

I'm having a lot of trouble in my Database program with trying to implement an effective DataGrid filtering method. After taking advice from a previous code review I'm trying to implement a DataModel method of coding. My previous method of searching my DataGrid was this;

**SearchGrid (PREVIOUS)**

```
private void SearchGrid(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dataGrid.ItemsSource as DataView;
        if (compNameRad.IsChecked == true)
        {
            dv.RowFilter = "CompanyName LIKE '%" + searchBox.Text + "%'";
        }
        if (compTownRad.IsChecked == true)
        {
            dv.RowFilter = "CompanyTown LIKE '%" + searchBox.Text + "%'";
        }
        if (compPcodeRad.IsChecked == true)
        {
            dv.RowFilter = "CompanyPcode LIKE '%" + searchBox.Text + "%'";
        }
    }
```

This worked fine with the way I bound my DataGrid before. I now bind my DataGrid using a Model class and the previous filter method does not work. I have written a new filter method which is this;

**SearchGrid (NEW)**

```
private void SearchGrid(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBox.Text))
            {
                ICollectionView view =      CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource);
                view.Filter += (obj) =>
                {
                    CompanyModel model = obj as CompanyModel;
                    if (model == null)
                        return true;

                    if (compNameRad.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CompanyName) && model.CompanyName.Contains(searchBox.Text);
                    }
                    if (compTownRad.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CompanyTown) && model.CompanyTown.Contains(searchBox.Text);
                     }
                    if (compPcodeRad.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CompanyPcode) && model.CompanyPcode.Contains(searchBox.Text);
                    }
                    return false;
                };
            }
        }
```

Now this does work OK, however there are two issues:

1. is that it is extremely slow when I type text to search the DataGrid, and
2. it doesn't deal with the most simple of cases, for example if the name of the Company is "A1" then searching for "a1" will not find the company.

I have been recommended to use Entity Framework however as I am using an OleDB connection (this is a very old Database I am rewriting) I have been unable to get this to work.

Is there a more efficient search method I can use that is quicker and would also find all companies (i.e case insensitive)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> private void SearchGrid(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBox.Text))
>         {
>             ICollectionView view =      CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource);
>             view.Filter += (obj) =>
>             {
>                 CompanyModel model = obj as CompanyModel;
>                 if (model == null)
>                     return true;
>
>                 if (compNameRad.IsChecked == true)
>                 {
>                     return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CompanyName) && model.CompanyName.Contains(searchBox.Text);
>                 }
>                 if (compTownRad.IsChecked == true)
>                 {
>                     return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CompanyTown) && model.CompanyTown.Contains(searchBox.Text);
>                 }
>                 if (compPcodeRad.IsChecked == true)
>                 {
>                     return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CompanyPcode) && model.CompanyPcode.Contains(searchBox.Text);
>                 }
>                 return false;
>             };
>         }
>     }
> ```

The problem with your code is that each time the text changed you are adding a new `Filter` to the `ICollectionView` by using

```
view.Filter += (obj) =>
```

this little `+` is doing all the harm. For each raise of the `TextChanged` event a new filter is added and never removed.

If you remove the `+` you will see that your filtering will become faster.

---

The problem with `A1` vs `a1` is that the `Contains()` method is case sensitive. A better way would be to use [`IndexOf(string, StringComparison)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like so

```
return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CompanyName)  
       && model.CompanyName.IndexOf(searchBox.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1;
```

Comment: Well, have to say that I totally ignored the `+` behavior on that bit. Guess you always learn not to underestimate the "small" bits :)

Comment: I appreciate your answer @GentianKasa and will work on your feedback though I have accepted this answer for the increase in filtering speed :)

Comment: @CBR, I totally agree with your choice :)

Answer (score 3):

Some small tweaks could be:

- Access the value of `searchBox.Text` only once and memorize it in a string that you use in the `Filter` event handler.
- use `stringValue != null` instead of `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue)`. In this way you avoid a method call and a check (if `stringValue` is `empty`) that is implicitly done in the `Contains(string)` method (`string.Empty.Contains(stringValue)` returns `false` for any `stringValue != string.Empty`)
- If possible, make it so the `Filter` delegate takes a `CompanyModel` instead of `object`.

The final result should be something like the following (not tested):

```
private void SearchGrid(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBox.Text))
    {
        return;
    }

    string searchText = searchBox.Text;
    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource);
    view.Filter += (model => 
    {
        if (model == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (compNameRad.IsChecked)
        {
            return model.CompanyName != null && model.CompanyName.Contains(searchText);
        }
        else if (compTownRad.IsChecked)
        {
            return model.CompanyTown != null && model.CompanyTown.Contains(searchText);
        }
        else if (compPcodeRad.IsChecked)
        {
            return model.CompanyPcode != null && model.CompanyPcode.Contains(searchText);
        }
        return false;
    };
}
```

and, by taking a look at the delegate, you could transform it (but it becomes a little less readable/understandable) into something like:

```
private void SearchGrid(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBox.Text))
    {
        return;
    }

    string searchText = searchBox.Text;
    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource);
    view.Filter += (model => 
    {
        return (model == null)
            || (compNameRad.IsChecked && model.CompanyName != null && model.CompanyName.Contains(searchText))
            || (compTownRad.IsChecked && model.CompanyTown != null && model.CompanyTown.Contains(searchText))
            || (compPcodeRad.IsChecked && model.CompanyPcode != null && model.CompanyPcode.Contains(searchText));
    };
}
```

which behaves in the same way as the original method by using only the lazy evaluation feature of the `||` and `&&` operator.

Regarding the search problem related to the case of the strings I'd just apply a `ToLower()` or `ToUpper()` to both strings. The end result should become the following:

```
private void SearchGrid(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBox.Text))
    {
        return;
    }

    string searchText = searchBox.Text.ToLower();
    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource);
    view.Filter += (model => 
    {
        return (model == null)
            || (compNameRad.IsChecked && model.CompanyName != null && model.CompanyName.ToLower().Contains(searchText))
            || (compTownRad.IsChecked && model.CompanyTown != null && model.CompanyTown.ToLower().Contains(searchText))
            || (compPcodeRad.IsChecked && model.CompanyPcode != null && model.CompanyPcode.ToLower().Contains(searchText));
    };
}
```

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

First, doing `variable == true` is redundant; `variable` by itself tests the `true` value.

Second, these conditions don't work in conjunction, so make them `if else` statements instead:

```
private void SearchGrid(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBox.Text))
            {
                ICollectionView view =      CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource);
                view.Filter += (obj) =>
                {
                    CompanyModel model = obj as CompanyModel;
                    if (model == null){
                        return true;
                    }

                    if (compNameRad.IsChecked) {
                        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CompanyName) && model.CompanyName.Contains(searchBox.Text);
                    } else if (compTownRad.IsChecked) {
                        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CompanyTown) && model.CompanyTown.Contains(searchBox.Text);
                    } else if (compPcodeRad.IsChecked) {
                        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CompanyPcode) && model.CompanyPcode.Contains(searchBox.Text);
                    }
                    return false;
                };
            }
        }
```

- The indentation on your opening brackets is incorrect.
- I would swap the `string.IsNullOrEmpty` check at the beginning around to remove the extraneous layer.
- The spacing on the `ICollectionView view` is incorrect.

  - When using `Linq`, shouldn't `(obj) => {obj.isLive};` be: `(obj => {obj.isLive});`

With those changes in mind:

```
private void SearchGrid(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBox.Text))
    {
        return;
    }
    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource);
    view.Filter += (obj => 
    {
        CompanyModel model = obj as CompanyModel;
        if (model == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (compNameRad.IsChecked)
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CompanyName) && model.CompanyName.Contains(searchBox.Text);
        }
        else if (compTownRad.IsChecked)
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CompanyTown) && model.CompanyTown.Contains(searchBox.Text);
        }
        else if (compPcodeRad.IsChecked)
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CompanyPcode) && model.CompanyPcode.Contains(searchBox.Text);
        }
        return false;
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. After implementing the code there is still a noticeable delay, especially when deleting characters from the search box. The old search method had no delay in filtering at all, I'm just wondering if I'm missing something obvious in why it is so slow now.